# How can I use the HTML data attribute in CSS as a property?

Tags: html, css

How can I use `attr()` to select the data attribute and set various CSS properties based off the value? For example I have this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rh1vfmso/ - I set the width via data-width then try to set it via `width: attr(data-width);`

It works when I set the content as the attribute but nothing else. How would I be able to set the width based off what's set in the attribute in HTML?

```
<style type='text/css'>
input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .size:before {
  content: attr(data-width);
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  width: attr(data-width);
  /*width: 100px;*/
}
</style>

<div>    
  <input type='checkbox' id='resize'>
  <label for='resize'>Resize</label>
  <div class="size" data-width=100px></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support would depend on the given browser's implementation. If it's not working, then it's not currently supported.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr), support for properties other than `content` is experimental:

> The `attr()` function can be used with any CSS property, but support for properties other than `content` is experimental.

Comment: d'oh I should have checked the compatibility chart. Thanks! (Can't accept answer for a few more minutes)

Comment: More like non-existent lol. See the dupe I just marked.

Comment: @BoltClock That's a good one. Thanks.